# How to do search view based on group by on a One2many field or on a relation table

Tags: python, odoo

I am facing a new problem with search in Openerp 7. When I am tring to group by some field of a relation table, it's not working.
As a example, I need Job Title (Database field: job_id) from Contract Module (hr_contract Table) with condition: primary_contract (customized field) will be 'Yes', but I will do group by on Job Title of Contract Table from Employee Module (hr_employee Table). Whereas, Job (Database field: job_id) already exists in Employee Module (hr_employee Table), but I don't want to group by on Job field of Employee table. I need group by based on Job Title of Contract table .Please, give me any solution.
Here is my code,

In employee_view_xml,

```
<record id="extend_view_employee_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Employees</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_filter"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="after">
            <filter icon="terp-go-month" 
                string="New Employee"
                domain="[('joining_date','&lt;=',(context_today()+relativedelta(day=31)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d')),('joining_date','&gt;=',(context_today()-relativedelta(day=1)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d'))]"
                help="Employees who have joined current month ...." />

            <filter icon="" 
                string="Unsigned Contract"
                domain="[('contract_ids', '=', False)]"
                help="Employees who have not any contract on Contract module ...." />

            <!-- <filter icon="" 
                string="Extend Contract"
                domain="['&amp;',('contract_ids.primary_contract', '=', 1),('contract_ids.date_end', '&gt;', (context_today().strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d')))]"
                help="Employees who need to extend contract ...." /> -->

            <filter icon="terp-go-month" 
                string="Resigned Employee"
                domain="[('leaving_date','&lt;=',(context_today()+relativedelta(day=31)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d')),('leaving_date','&gt;=',(context_today()-relativedelta(day=1)).strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d'))]"
                help="Employees who have resigned current month ...." />
        </xpath>           
        <xpath expr="//group[@string='Group By...']/filter[@string='Company']" position="after">
            <filter string="Joining Date" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'joining_date'}"/>
            <filter string="Team" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'team_id'}"/>
            <filter name="get_group_by_job_of_contracts" string="Job (Contract)" domain="[('contract_ids.primary_contract', '=', 1)]" context="{'group_by': 'contract_ids[0]'}" />
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

In employee.py,

```
'contract_ids': fields.one2many('hr.contract', 'employee_id', string='All Contracts', required=False, domain=[('active','=',True)], store=True)
```

In contract.py,

```
'employee_id': fields.many2one('hr.employee', "Employee", required=True)
'job_id': fields.many2one('hr.job', 'Job Title')
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to group by a `many2many` or `one2many` field. List views aren't designed for it. You already understood that, because you're trying to use the first contract on an employee. But that's not working anyway.

If you really want to use the first contract for group by, define a related field on `hr.employee` related to `contract_ids.job_id`:

```py
_columns = {
    'first_contract_job_id': fields.related(
        'contract_ids', 'job_id', type='many2one',
        relation='hr.job', string='First Contract's Job', store=True),
}
```

That should take the first contract's `job_id`. It's important to store this field, because Odoo can't group by non database persistent fields.
But i'm not fully sure it will work, because the first example for such a related field on a `one2many` was used in Odoo V8 on for example `product.template`. Just try it out.

If you have more than one contract for an employee, you should use a computed field instead of a related field.

Comment: Thanks @CZoellner. I will try this way.